# SearchBar is not returning my search into Contacts

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working with Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2 and I was trying to search to my list of contacts using a SearchBar, all done except that the SearchBar is returning index out of bounds. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var contactList: [CNContact]!
var inSearchMode = false
var filteredData = [CNContact]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let store = CNContactStore()
    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
        if success {
            let keys = CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()
            let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [keys])
            do {
                self.contactList = []
                try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, status) in
                    self.contactList.append(contact)
                })
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Last night I made search func here on stack and all is fine except for that error that throws when running the app. How can I solve it?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if contactList != nil {
        return contactList.count
    }
    if inSearchMode {
        return filteredData.count
    }
    return 0
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath)
    let contact: CNContact!

    contact = contactList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"

    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let contact = contactList[indexPath.row]
    let controller = CNContactViewController(for: contact)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else{
       inSearchMode = true
       filteredData = contactList.filter {
            $0.givenName.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil ||
            $0.familyName.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil
        }
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath)
let contact: CNContact!

if inSearchMode {
    contact = filteredData[indexPath.row]
} else {
    contact = contactList[indexPath.row]
}

cell.textLabel?.text = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"

return cell
}
```

you should check if you are in search mode or not in cellForRow to fetch correctly

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if inSearchMode {
    return filteredData.count
}
if contactList != nil {
    return contactList.count
}
return 0
}
```

when you call reloadData() -numberOfRows -CellForRow are recalling also